# How do you add a JButton icon from a web image?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, imageicon

I have a `JButton` and I am tired of loading an icon from my computer.
How can I open a image from the web? I've tried to just add the like adress, but it doesn't show up on the button.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("http://s22.postimg.org/4gttei2rl/nv070_binary_jpg.jpg");
jButton1.setIcon(icon);
```

[image: What it looks like after I run the code.]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `ImageIcon` is consuming the *"Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://s22.postimg.org/4gttei2rl/nv070_binary_jpg.jpg"* error, which is a forbidden error, which means the server won't let you read the image

Comment: You could use Apache's HTTPComponents API to "fake" a web browser, which might allow you to download the image

Comment: `new ImageIcon("http://s22.postimg.org/4gttei2rl/nv070_binary_jpg.jpg");` should be `new ImageIcon(new URL("http://s22.postimg.org/4gttei2rl/nv070_binary_jpg.jpg"));` The first form will have the API attempt to load the `URL` as if it were a `File` (which it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code - it deals with several issues you have:

- That image checks for "Browser" access - so we change the User-Agent to access it.
- Loading from URL and keeping track with MediaTracker is replaces with Common IO method to read image into byte array

With this in mind here's the working code:

```
  public class Panel extends JPanel {

      public Panel() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton();
        URL url = new URL("http://s22.postimg.org/4gttei2rl/nv070_binary_jpg.jpg");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(IOUtils.toByteArray(uc.getInputStream()));

        btnNewButton.setIcon(icon);
        add(btnNewButton);
      }

      public static void main(String[] a)  {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  new Panel());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
  }
```